# Android manifest (AndroidManifest.xml) not working as expected

Tags: android, android-manifest

What is the problem in this file ?

it give me error everytime i try to make it work

i need the splash screen to work as normal

then i want the `StationList` work after it as i try to do when splash is working good the stationlist don't and when stationlist work the splash screen dont

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webcraftbd.radio"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="@string/version" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="androiåd.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"            
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >            
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StationList"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".RadioService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" ></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FacebookActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" ></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TwitterActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" ></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Cant understand what you mean

Comment: Unable to get your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this: `android:name=".StationList"` in

```
<activity
        android:name=".StationList"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

with the name of your splashscreen activity and add .StationList as a seperate activity like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".StationList" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" ></activity>
```